# Create a jpeg from data piece by piece in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, swift3

I'm using NSURLSession to get a series of partial jpeg data chunks. Since the whole jpeg image is around 3-8 chunks, I have to wait until all of the chunks are received to then use UImage(data: imageData) to load the image. However since I'm trying to do this 20 times a second I want to be able to have the image load as fast as possible. Is there a way in Swift to load a partial jpeg image as each data chunk is received?

Comment: Have you tried using NSURLSession?

Comment: Yeah! I'm using NSURLSession to get the data chunks. Each jpeg image is anywhere from 3-8 chunks. The problem isn't getting the data but being able to convert it to a jpeg once the data is received. If I try to create a UIImage with just one chunk it returns an empty image.

Comment: "Yeah! I'm using NSURLSession to get the data chunks."  Nobody sees that but you.

Comment: Do you mean I should include that in the question? Sorry, I'm still getting used to how to properly use this site.

Comment: Are you using progressive JPEGs ? Some libraries support progressive decoding.

Comment: The data stream is coming from a Sony camera and their API doesn't specify if the jpegs are progressive or not. Is there a way to test if a jpeg is progressive?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33154022/how-to-determine-if-an-image-is-a-progressive-jpeg-interlaced-in-objective-c or http://highloadtools.com/progressivejpeg

Comment: That seems promising! Would it be more helpful if it was a baseline jpeg?